# How to display text on JFrame or JPanel?

Tags: java, jframe

I want to display some text on a window, should I use `JFrame` or `JFanel`?  What is the difference between those two and how can I add text to a window?

I am using eclipse, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

A **JFrame** is a top-level window with a title and a border.
A **JPanel**  provides general-purpose containers for lightweight components, such as textfields, buttons and more.

You will need to use both JFrame and JPanel, you create the JFrame and then add a Panel, wich will contain your textfield:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title for your window");

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel label = new JLabel("Your text here");

panel.add(label);

frame.add(panel);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: That's half correct. A ``JFrame`` hosts a [``JRootPane``](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) which has multiple container layers, such as the ``contentPane`` which is a ``JPanel`` by default; a call to ``JFrame#add(Component)`` is equivalent to ``myJFrame.getRootPane().getContentPane().add(myComponent)``, so you don't need to create a ``JPanel`` *explicit*.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, but still it is good practice to create the components, and add to panels, right?

Comment: Containers like ``JPanel`` are designed to group and align components on the GUI. If you see logical component groups it is for sure a good practice to wrap them all together in a container.

Comment: Actually am a beginner , can you display the full program for me please,  I just want to display some text on a window by using system.out.printline